# Mysql Date_format error

Tags: php, syntax-error

I always get this error message:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /myroot/public_html/test.php on line 5
This is what the 5th line looks like:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT date_format(active,'%a/%b/%Y') AS active FROM members")  
or die mysql_error();
```

I can't find anything wrong with the code as i copied it from another stackoverflow question
Here's the whole script:
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT date_format(active,'%a/%b/%Y') AS active FROM members")
    or die mysql_error();
    while ($results = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
    $date = $results["active"];
    $user = $results["user"];
    }

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: Your SQL query is ok. See [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/1246)

Comment: Retagged this. This problem is related to PHP syntax, and just because it happens to be a line in which you have written MySQL, it doesn't make it MySQL-specific.

Answer (score 2):

This is a PHP error but anyway.. Try changing

```
or die mysql_error();
```

to

```
or die (mysql_error());
```

Edit (forgot the obligatory 'don't use mysql_*' so here it is):
And please don't use the mysql_ functions in new code, they are deprecated.